# How do I fix a counterweighted accordion blind that is stuck?

Tags: blinds

We have accordion style blinds.
[image: blinds]
These are assisted...meaning that we can raise and lower the blinds just by lifting or pulling down. No need to pull any strings directly.

Now the assist mechanism is not working anymore. The mechanism is at the top of the blinds. [image: mechanism]

A string enters the mechanism from the right and the left.

I tried to pull on the string to see if I can get the mechanism to release/unwind the string but I had no luck.

Any suggestion from people that know this mechanism? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you be descriptive in what you mean by 'not working'?  Does it not hold its position or does it not want to move at all.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to one of our cordless blinds (made by Bali), they were stuck and would not raise or lower. I'm not certain that all types are made the same, but in the Bali blinds at least you can remove the top cover and there are one or more spring tensioned cylinders (for lack of a better term), and the blind cord may be wrapped around one of them incorrectly.

It's not fun, but I had to unspool and respool all of the blind cords until all were wound correctly around their cylinders, which required a surprising amount of force. I'm sure this makes little sense as typed, so here's a youtube video that helped. Your blinds may be a little different if they're from a different manufacturer.

[Bali cordless blinds won't go up or down (not my content)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0s3dTHF9ak)

Answer (score 0):

Would think that the assisted action is with a counter weight somewhere. Perhaps that counter weight is stuck somewhere and you need to free it. Based on your description the weight of the blind is 'balanced' and will thus stop wherever you leave it. This makes me think there ought to be a counter weight somewhere. Much like elevators or lifts.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the question description where you advise it is indeed 'counterweighted' so yes, you might need to look at the counterweight mechanism itself to see if it is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps helpful:
It turns out that many of such blinds are covered by a 'lifetime' warranty.  If you're the original purchaser and/or can identify the vendor, you may be able to get an replacement.  That would take the form of a new blind, matching the old.